# Wrapper with height 100% displaing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

How to remove scrollbar and display footer in bottom of page?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    wrapper
</div>
<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eoe26o83/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: @CaseyFalk, if I add `overflow: hidden;` to body then footer will be hidden. Padding and margin already setted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem above is that you have height of wrapper at 100%, leaving "no room" on that page for the footer. It necessarily is placed after 100% of the page is used, thus forcing a scroll.

Instead, you can change the position of the footer to be fixed, and always be on the bottom of the page.

```
footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eoe26o83/4/

Comment: This isn't a good idea....the footer should stay in the flow of the document in case the content is taller than the Viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Use calc() in your CSS. The only caveat is you need to know the height of your footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/eoe26o83/9/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <p>wrapper</p>
</div>
<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
footer {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;    
}
```